# How can I add an additional constraint into lp() (that all values are non-zero)? - R

Tags: r, constraints, linear-programming

```
u    <- runif(8,min=1,max=7) 
prob <- runif(8)
prob <- prob/sum(prob)
U    <- prob%*%u
```

Above, U is a weighted sum of 8 u values (all between 1 and 7). I would like to write a simple lp() that backs-out a solution for the weights where all weights are non-zero. This will be the starting values for candidate weights.

So far I have the following (which just finds weights, most of which are 0, as this is the simplest solution):

```
obj.fun <- rep(1,8)
constr <- rbind(q,rep(1,8))
constr.dir <- c("==","==")
rhs <- c(Q,1)
p.start <- lp("max",obj.fun,constr,constr.dir,rhs)$sol
```

How can I add another constraint that I want all weights to be non-zero?

Comment: Add a lower-bound on each weight?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to achieve, but I havent been able to get the code to work. I have added ">" into the constr.dir , and 0s into the constr, but it's not working...

Comment: Although lpsolve supports bounds, this R package does not. That means you need to specify `x(i) >= lo` as an explicit constraint. So you need to add an identity matrix to `constr`

Comment: Aha OK! I will have a go! Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen is this close to what I need? Not working yet...

`obj.fun <- rep(1,8)`  <br/>
`constr <- rbind(q,rep(1,8),rep(1,8))`  <br/>
`constr.dir <- c("==","==",">=")`  <br/>
`rhs <- c(Q,1,0)`  <br/>
`p.start <- lp("max",obj.fun,constr,constr.dir,rhs)$sol`

Comment: This is a bit difficult to read but I expected to see few `diag(nrow=n)`